# Get InterfaceMethod-pendant from TargetMethod by InterfaceMapping

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, attributes, delegates

I have a property on a class which is implemented by an interface. Now I want to get all attributes from a specific type declared on that property and their interface Pendants.

In order to regard multi implementation with implicit and explicit members I wrote an test-class (with xUnit).

```cs
[DebuggerDisplay("{Tooltip}")]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class TooltipAttribute : Attribute
{
    public TooltipAttribute(string tooltip)
    {
        Tooltip = tooltip;
    }

    public string Tooltip { get; set; }
}

public interface IAmGood
{
    [Tooltip("GOOD: I am a very generic description.")]
    int Length { get; }
}

public interface IAmBad
{
    [Tooltip("BAD: This description is not wanted to be shown.")]
    int Length { get; }
}

public class DemoClassImplicit : IAmGood, IAmBad
{
    [Tooltip("GOOD: Implicit")]
    public int Length => throw new NotImplementedException();

    [Tooltip("BAD: Explicit")]
    int IAmBad.Length => throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public class DemoClassExplicit : IAmGood, IAmBad
{
    [Tooltip("GOOD: Explicit")]
    int IAmGood.Length => throw new NotImplementedException();

    [Tooltip("BAD: Implicit")]
    public int Length => throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public class DemoClassImplicitForBoth : IAmGood, IAmBad
{
    [Tooltip("I am GOOD and BAD")]
    public int Length => throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public class TestClass
{
    [Fact]
    public void GetTooltipFromImplicit()
    {
        var demoClassImplicit = new DemoClassImplicit();
        var propertyInfo = demoClassImplicit.GetType().GetRuntimeProperty("Length");

        var tooltips = GetTooltipAttribute<TooltipAttribute>(propertyInfo);

        Assert.Equal(2, tooltips.Count());
        Assert.All(tooltips, o => Assert.Contains("GOOD", o.Tooltip));
    }

    [Fact]
    public void GetTooltipFromExplicit()
    {
        var demoClassImplicit = new DemoClassExplicit();
        var propertyInfo = demoClassImplicit.GetType().GetRuntimeProperties().First(o => o.Name.EndsWith(".Length"));

        var tooltips = GetTooltipAttribute<TooltipAttribute>(propertyInfo);

        Assert.Equal(2, tooltips.Count());
        Assert.All(tooltips, o => Assert.Contains("GOOD", o.Tooltip));
    }

    [Fact]
    public void GetTooltipFromImplicitForBoth()
    {
        var demoClassImplicit = new DemoClassImplicitForBoth();
        var propertyInfo = demoClassImplicit.GetType().GetRuntimeProperty("Length");

        var tooltips = GetTooltipAttribute<TooltipAttribute>(propertyInfo);

        Assert.Equal(3, tooltips.Count());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The core method.
    /// </summary>
    public IEnumerable<T_Attribute> GetTooltipAttribute<T_Attribute>(PropertyInfo propInfo)
        where T_Attribute : Attribute
    {
        var result = new List<T_Attribute>(propInfo.GetCustomAttributes<T_Attribute>());

        var declaringType = propInfo.DeclaringType;
        // The get method is required for comparing without use the prop name.
        var getMethodFromGivenProp = propInfo.GetGetMethod(true);

        // Check for each interface if the given property is declared there 
        // (it is not a naming check!).
        foreach (var interfaceType in declaringType.GetInterfaces())
        {
            var map = declaringType.GetInterfaceMap(interfaceType);

            // Check if the current interface has an member for given props get method.
            // Attend that compare by naming would be cause an invalid result here!
            var targetMethod = map.TargetMethods.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Equals(getMethodFromGivenProp));
            if (targetMethod != null)
            {
                // Get the equivalent get method on interface side.
                // ERROR: The error line!
                var interfaceMethod = map.InterfaceMethods.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Name == targetMethod.Name);
                if (interfaceMethod != null)
                {
                    // The get method does not help to get the attribute so the property is required.
                    // In order to get the property we must look which one has the found get method.
                    var property = interfaceType.GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(o => o.GetGetMethod() == interfaceMethod);
                    if (property != null)
                    {
                        var attributes = property.GetCustomAttributes<T_Attribute>();
                        if (attributes != null)
                        {
                            result.AddRange(attributes);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

The test method 'GetTooltipFromExplicit' fails because in the core method is a comparison by name. I marked the line above with `// ERROR: The error line!`.

I have no idea how to find the method-pendant inside of 'InterfaceMapping'-class.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to know that the order of the two collections in **InterfaceMapping** are mirrorred.

So replace the line below is the solution:

```cs
// ERROR: The error line!
var interfaceMethod = map.InterfaceMethods.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Name == targetMethod.Name);

// SOLUTION: The working line:
var interfaceMethod = map.InterfaceMethods[Array.IndexOf(map.TargetMethods, targetMethod)];
```

This detailed was explained on official member documentation (but not on the class itself). See:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.interfacemapping.interfacemethods?view=netcore-3.1#remarks
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.interfacemapping.targetmethods?view=netcore-3.1#remarks